# access custom color variables in tailwind.config.js file

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a project with nextjs and typescript. in this project I use tailwind. I defined some colors and a keyframe in tailwind.config.js file. for that keyframe object I defined a background color and my problem is how can I access my colors to use as keyframe background value.

this is my tailwind.config.js file

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    important: true,
    content: [
        './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
        './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
    ],
    theme: {
        colors: {
            transparent: 'transparent',
            current: 'currentColor',
            white: '#ffffff',
            black: '#000000',
            primary: '#1D82DD',
            'primary-dark': '#1767AF',
            'primary-darker': '#114C81',
            secondary: '#ffa41c',
            error: '#DC362E',
            'error-bg': '#FFFBF9',
            'error-bg-dark': '#FEF6F6',
            success: '#00BDB1',
            'success-bg': '#1DDDD708',
            warning: '#ffa41c',
            'warning-bg': '#fff2df',
            'warning-bg-dark': '#FFFAF3',
            info: '#1D82DD',
            'info-bg': '#F8FAFD',
            'info-bg-dark': '#F3F7FB',
            'info-bg-darker': '#E8F0F7',
            disabled: '#D3D9DD',
            text: '#041320',
            grey: {
                1: '#F7F8FA',
                2: '#E9ECEE',
                3: '#F9F9FB',
                4: '#7A8C9A',
                5: '#566571',
                6: '#F2F3F5',
                7: '#677887',
                8: '#9BA9B3',
                9: '#FBFBFC',
            },
        },
        screens: {
            '3xl': { max: '1650px' },
            // => @media (max-width: 1650px) { ... }

            '2xl': { max: '1440px' },
            // => @media (max-width: 1440px) { ... }

            xl: { max: '1280px' },
            // => @media (max-width: 1280px) { ... }

            lg: { max: '1024px' },
            // => @media (max-width: 1024px) { ... }
        },
        extend: {
            keyframes: {
                'dot-flashing': {
                    '0%': {
                        backgroundColor: '#1D82DD',
                    },
                    '50%, 100%': {
                        backgroundColor: '#1D82DD20',
                    },
                },
            },
            content: {
                empty: '',
            },
            transitionProperty: {
                width: 'width',
                height: 'height',
            },
            flex: {
                2: '2 2 0%',
            },
            fontSize: {
                '2xs': '10px',
            },
            maxWidth: {
                886: '886px',
            },
        },
    },
    plugins: [],
};
```

actually I want something like this

```
 keyframes: {
            'dot-flashing': {
                '0%': {
                    backgroundColor: 'primary',
                },
                '50%, 100%': {
                    backgroundColor: 'primary20',
                },
            },
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had simillar problem, didn't manage to figure out how to use colors directly in `tailwind.config.js`, however I've managed to set keyframes style in css using tailwind classes.

```css
@layer utilities {
    @keyframes select { 100% { @apply bg-green-500 text-white }}
    @keyframes dot-flashing { 
        0% { @apply bg-primary }
        100% { @apply bg-primary-20 }
    }

}
```

```js
animation: {
    "select": "select 2s ease-in-out forwards"
}
```

Hope that was somewhat helpful.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: the theme colours don't have to be HSL, I have just used that here

You can do it like this:

```
import { type Config } from 'tailwindcss'

export const extendedTheme = {
    keyframes: {
        btnpulse: {
            '0%': { 'box-shadow': '0 0 0 0 theme("colors.secondary.DEFAULT")' },
            '50%': { 'box-shadow': '0 0 0 0 theme("colors.secondary.DEFAULT/50")' },
            '100%': {
                'box-shadow': '0 0 0 12px theme("colors.secondary.DEFAULT/0")',
            },
        },
    },
    colors: {
        border: 'hsl(var(--border))',
        input: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--input))',
            invalid: 'hsl(var(--input-invalid))',
        },
        ring: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--ring))',
            invalid: 'hsl(var(--foreground-destructive))',
        },
        background: 'hsl(var(--background))',
        foreground: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--foreground))',
            destructive: 'hsl(var(--foreground-destructive))',
        },
        primary: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--primary))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--primary-foreground))',
        },
        secondary: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--secondary))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--secondary-foreground))',
        },
        destructive: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--destructive))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--destructive-foreground))',
        },
        muted: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--muted))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--muted-foreground))',
        },
        accent: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--accent))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--accent-foreground))',
        },
        popover: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--popover))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--popover-foreground))',
        },
        card: {
            DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--card))',
            foreground: 'hsl(var(--card-foreground))',
        },
    },
    borderColor: {
        DEFAULT: 'hsl(var(--border))',
    },
    borderRadius: {
        lg: 'var(--radius)',
        md: 'calc(var(--radius) - 2px)',
        sm: 'calc(var(--radius) - 4px)',
    },
    fontSize: {
        // 1rem = 16px
        /** 80px size / 84px high / bold */
        mega: ['5rem', { lineHeight: '5.25rem', fontWeight: '700' }],
        /** 56px size / 62px high / bold */
        h1: ['3.5rem', { lineHeight: '3.875rem', fontWeight: '700' }],
        /** 40px size / 48px high / bold */
        h2: ['2.5rem', { lineHeight: '3rem', fontWeight: '700' }],
        /** 32px size / 36px high / bold */
        h3: ['2rem', { lineHeight: '2.25rem', fontWeight: '700' }],
        /** 28px size / 36px high / bold */
        h4: ['1.75rem', { lineHeight: '2.25rem', fontWeight: '700' }],
        /** 24px size / 32px high / bold */
        h5: ['1.5rem', { lineHeight: '2rem', fontWeight: '700' }],
        /** 16px size / 20px high / bold */
        h6: ['1rem', { lineHeight: '1.25rem', fontWeight: '700' }],

        /** 32px size / 36px high / normal */
        'body-2xl': ['2rem', { lineHeight: '2.25rem' }],
        /** 28px size / 36px high / normal */
        'body-xl': ['1.75rem', { lineHeight: '2.25rem' }],
        /** 24px size / 32px high / normal */
        'body-lg': ['1.5rem', { lineHeight: '2rem' }],
        /** 20px size / 28px high / normal */
        'body-md': ['1.25rem', { lineHeight: '1.75rem' }],
        /** 16px size / 20px high / normal */
        'body-sm': ['1rem', { lineHeight: '1.25rem' }],
        /** 14px size / 18px high / normal */
        'body-xs': ['0.875rem', { lineHeight: '1.125rem' }],
        /** 12px size / 16px high / normal */
        'body-2xs': ['0.75rem', { lineHeight: '1rem' }],

        /** 18px size / 24px high / semibold */
        caption: ['1.125rem', { lineHeight: '1.5rem', fontWeight: '600' }],
        /** 12px size / 16px high / bold */
        button: ['0.75rem', { lineHeight: '1rem', fontWeight: '700' }],
    },
} satisfies Config['theme']
```